# How can I tell if something is a property or a method?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, methods

I am new to programming.
Using C# & ASP.Net, how would I differentiate between a property & a method?
How can I tell if something is a property or a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio displays different icons in the IntelliSense list. It's mentioned in the documentation too:

[Visual Studio IntelliSense list http://img1.myimg.de/intellisense88c76.png](http://img1.myimg.de/intellisense88c76.png)

You don't use parenthesis to access properties but you always do when you're calling methods.

Comment: so if something has parenthesis, it is always a method?

Comment: No. Parenthesis are used in other places like overriding precedence in expressions too.

Comment: Can you provide an example of precedence in expressions ?

Comment: I'd say that's almost coorect but stating that you always use parenthesis when _declaring_ a method would be even more correct. After all
someEvent += someName; is valid if someName is a property (with a delegate suitable for the expression) or a method with a signature matching the delegate. (I know it's not a method call, but you can use methods without calling them)

Comment: Rune FS: I explicitly mentioned "calling" in my second line. Anyway, that's just a side note. The question was about identifying what's a method and what's a property and looking at the icon is the best way.

Comment: C# can be quite confusing to start with. Take a property returning a delegate, this can result in `Foo.Property()`

Comment: Indeed. The `()` is not really a way to distinguish a method from a property. I wrote that to tell the OP how he should use it.

Comment: I know. More people struggle with (), in any language. Had one asking why a function taking nothing has to be used with (), it seemed useless to him. Didn't have a clear explanation.

Comment: @Dykam to distinguish it from a property. if the () was omitted the compiler would look for a property (except if the left hand side was expecting a delegate where it would take the method without () as a delegate)

Comment: Rune FS: The compiler can do this without `()`. A method and a property can't have identical names.

Answer (score 1):

Method calls have to be called with parenthesis, where not with Properties

Comment: Depends on the language. Although Visual Studio will automatically insert parentheses into VB.NET code, VB.NET doesn't require parentheses to call methods which take 0 parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Juliet. Though I am using C#, this is good to know about VB

Comment: The question stated it was for C#

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (i.e. not using intellisense) is to call the method/property and compile your code. If you've used the wrong syntax the compiler will let you know.